# Run script after user event, but without affecting page loading?

Tags: php, scripting

I'd like to trigger a script to update some statistics when a user submits a new record, but I don't want the user to have to wait for the script to finish before being redirected.

```
>-- Time -->
                        > redirect User -> User Does Stuff -> more stuff -> etc
                       /                   
User Input -> Submit ->
                       \
                        > updating stats in background -> Possibly still running
```

What's the best way to do this in PHP?

**EDIT for Fabrik**

Users would like to see immediate feedback reflecting the addition of their new data, but this new data only comes in 2 or 3 times a day, so I think an interval-based CRON job might be an unnecessary use of server resources and also fail to satisfy their need for urgency. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick google search for [php background process](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=ja&source=hp&q=php+background+process&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) and most of the hits are suggesting using either [`exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [`shell_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to call the script you want to run in the background.

Edit:
[This article](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/running-background-processes-in-php-349/) seems to be the most relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a small code snippet i'd go for something like this:

```
<?php
if($new_record) {
  exec("php /path/updateStats.php ".escapeshellarg($userid)." >/dev/null &");
  your_redirect_call_etc();
}
```

redirecting the output stream and the '&' will lead to the exec call running independently from the the script.

If you need a bigger / scaleable solution you could look into something like [Gearman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gearman) which would allow you to run those background jobs on another server easily / controlled.

Answer (score 0):

Nice chart but:

- We need to know more about your needs (e.g. is it possible to use cron or we need to display the stats asap?)
- If you can use cron set up a small interval (5 mins) then poll your database for changes
- If you can't use cron try to build your site fully with AJAX so you can safely run background processes